# Passing a form as a local to a ajax rendered partial in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked all over and can't find a solution that works.

Relevant Controller (profits_controller.rb):

```
def new_tabs
    @market = Market.order('mjsnumber').all.first
    @profit = Profit.new
    profit_types_markets_products
end

def fetch_market
    @market = Market.where(:id => params[:market_id]).first
    form = params["form"]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render layout: false}
    end
end
```

Relevant View (new_tabs.html.erb):

```
<%= simple_form_for @profit, :remote => true do |form| %> 
<% @markets.each_with_index do |market, i| %>
     <%= link_to market.nick, fetch_market_path(:market_id => market.id, :form => form, profit: @profit), :remote=>'true', :id => 'navBtn' + market.id.to_s, :class => 'd-flex flex-grow-1 align-content-center text-center nav-item nav-link ' + active(i).to_s + profit_nav_font_color(market.color).to_s, "data-toggle" => "pill", "roll" => "tab", "style" => "background-color: " + market.color.to_s + ";", remote: true %>
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => 'edit_partial_form', locals: { market: @market, form: form, profit: @profit } %>
```

Relevant Partial (_edit_partial_form.html.erb):

```
<%= form.simple_fields_for :figures, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "floatTextBox" }}, remote: true do |figures_form| %>
    <%= figures_form.input "[test]" %>
<% end %>
```

Relevant JS (fetch_market.erb):

```
$("#edit_partial_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'edit_partial_form', locals: { market: @market, form: form, profit: @profit } ) %>");
```

Routes:

```
    get "/fetch_market" => 'profits#fetch_market', as: 'fetch_market'
```

It renders the partial fine, and the links appear to contain the FormBuilder information. When I click the link and add a "puts params" to the controller, it shows the params there. But then gives me an error when loading the partial in console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class:0x00007fdbd6453648>:0x00007fdbd68db5f8>
Did you mean?  fork):
    1: $("#edit_partial_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'edit_partial_form', locals: { market: @market, form: form, profit: @profit } ) %>");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question which by adding file name as well, that will help us debug the rendering issue.

Comment: Thanks, edited to add the file names.

Comment: Ok, the `fetch_market.erb` will be call first, but the name should be `fetch_market.js.erb` and it will call partial `edit_partial_form` and there will be nothing related to `new_tabs` file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fetch_market method you should to edit `form = params["form"]` to `@form = params["form"]`. You was declared local var this is why your code doesnt work. And the name of the file should be `fetch_market.js.erb)`

Comment: Thank you! This worked so I'm marking this problem as solved. However, it looks like I now have a new and seperate problem related to the SimpleForm gem.

"ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `simple_fields_for' for "#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x00007f6e69c80878>..."

Comment: No problem) Can you make a new topic with all associated files?

Comment: Thanks again. Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600451/error-in-rails-5-rendering-simple-form-in-partial-undefined-method-simple-fi