# Error in Rails 5 rendering form in partial: " undefined method `simple_fields_for' for "#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder "

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is a continuation from here:
[Passing a form as a local to a ajax rendered partial in Rails 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584478/passing-a-form-as-a-local-to-a-ajax-rendered-partial-in-rails-5/58587570?noredirect=1#comment103491300_58587570)

I've looked all over and can't find a solution that works.

Relevant Controller (profits_controller.rb):

```
def new_tabs
    @market = Market.order('mjsnumber').all.first
    @profit = Profit.new
    profit_types_markets_products
end

def fetch_market
    @market = Market.where(:id => params[:market_id]).first
    @form = params["form"]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render layout: false}
    end
end
```

Relevant View (new_tabs.html.erb):

```
<%= simple_form_for @profit, :remote => true do |form| %> 
<% @markets.each_with_index do |market, i| %>
     <%= link_to market.nick, fetch_market_path(:market_id => market.id, :form => form, profit: @profit), :remote=>'true', :id => 'navBtn' + market.id.to_s, :class => 'd-flex flex-grow-1 align-content-center text-center nav-item nav-link ' + active(i).to_s + profit_nav_font_color(market.color).to_s, "data-toggle" => "pill", "roll" => "tab", "style" => "background-color: " + market.color.to_s + ";", remote: true %>
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => 'edit_partial_form', locals: { market: @market, form: form, profit: @profit } %>
```

Relevant Partial (_edit_partial_form.html.erb):

```
<%= market.namae %>
<%= form.simple_fields_for :figures, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "floatTextBox" }}, remote: true do |figures_form| %>
    <%= figures_form.input "[test]" %>
<% end %>
```

Relevant JS (fetch_market.js.erb):

```
$("#edit_partial_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'edit_partial_form', locals: { market: @market, form: @form, profit: @profit } ) %>");
```

Routes:

```
resources :profits do
    resources :markets
    resources :products
    collection do
        get 'new_by_product_type'
        get 'new_tabs'
    end
end
get "/fetch_market" => 'profits#fetch_market', as: 'fetch_market'
patch 'profits/:id/autosave', as: :autosave_profit, to: 'profits#autosave'
```

It renders the partial fine, and the links appear to contain the FormBuilder information. When I click the link and add a "puts params" to the controller, it shows the params there. But then gives me an error when loading the partial in console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class:0x00007fdbd6453648>:0x00007fdbd68db5f8>
Did you mean?  fork):
    1: $("#edit_partial_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'edit_partial_form', locals: { market: @market, form: form, profit: @profit } ) %>");
```

Full Error from local environment when I click on the link for the second market in the list of generated markets:

```
Processing by ProfitsController#fetch_market as JS
  Parameters: {"form"=>"#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x00007fed50dba9f8>", "market_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/mudl/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Market Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "markets".* FROM "markets" WHERE "markets"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "markets"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/profits_controller.rb:75
  Rendering profits/fetch_market.js.erb
  Rendered profits/_edit_partial_form.html.erb (6.5ms)
  Rendered profits/fetch_market.js.erb (7.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `simple_fields_for' for "#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x00007fed50dba9f8>":String):
    11:                                 MJS 番後： <%= market.mjsnumber %>
    12:                         </span>
    13:                 </div>
    14:                 <%= form.simple_fields_for :figures, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "floatTextBox" }}, remote: true do |figures_form| %>
    15:                         <%= figures_form.input "[test]" %>
    16:                 <% end %>
    17:

app/views/profits/_edit_partial_form.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_profits__edit_partial_form_html_erb__249336059151108365_70328546926840'
app/views/profits/fetch_market.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_profits_fetch_market_js_erb___2023159631102932010_70328546933900'
app/controllers/profits_controller.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_market'
app/controllers/profits_controller.rb:77:in `fetch_market'
(undefined method `simple_fields_for' for "#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder
```

I am removing the simple_form tag because after a simple test changing the simple_form to a regular form, the error persists with whatever method I call after field_for in the partial.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So I ended up giving up and just using the @profit variable to make a new form in the partial (not ideal, but I'll hack it). Still curious if this is even possible, though, so I'll leave the question open..

Comment: are you sure you add simple_form to Gemfile?

Comment: Yup, always good to check that, though, lol.

From Gemfile:
`gem 'simple_form'`

Comment: make sure do `bundle install` too. Check documentation at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: 'bundle install' was done, and simple_form is working on other parts of the site without issues. Edited to add that I tested without simple_form. The problem persists without this gem. I suspect is must have something to do with the formbuilder processing the form sent as a param?

Comment: From the error it looks like param for the form is a string: `"#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x00007fed50dba9f8>":String` How do I get the param to send as the form itself instead of a string...

Comment: form builder is view helper. I think you just need to remove local variable form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201522/discussion-between-mudl-and-dieu-linh).

Comment: If I have understood this correctly your javascript handler should render a form inside a form. Thats not a good idea since the HTML specification does not allow nested forms and the behavior is very unpredictable. https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html

Comment: It _should_ be the same form. I wanted to render parts of the form inside the partial. The goal of this is that there are about 50 markets and each have tens of products, it's a heavy load on the server. I just waned to load bits at a time have have them automatically submit via Ajax on click and input triggers. But, I couldn't get the form partials to render.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you need to close your form block, then if you couldn`t pass form to partial then try to do this without partial

```
<%= simple_form_for @profit, remote: true do |form| %> 
  <% @markets.each_with_index do |market, i| %>
     <%= link_to market.nick, fetch_market_path(market_id: market.id, form: form, profit: @profit), id: 'navBtn' + market.id.to_s, class: 'd-flex flex-grow-1 align-content-center text-center nav-item nav-link ' + active(i).to_s + profit_nav_font_color(market.color).to_s, "data-toggle" => "pill", "roll" => "tab", "style" => "background-color: " + market.color.to_s + ";", remote: true %>
     <%= market.name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.simple_fields_for :figures, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "floatTextBox" }}, remote: true do |figures_form| %>
    <%= figures_form.input "[test]" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And better to used `something_key: "value"` instead of this syntax `:something_key => "value"`

Comment: I had it closed in the original app, I only quoted relevant code here to save space. 

The solution I am currently using involves getting rid of the form going into the partial entirely. The problem is with passing the form object as a variable to render the partial content with JS, I'm not sure you can pass an object like that, just a string?